# Cannot find OpenTK.Audio.OpenAL C# Tutorial

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, opentk, openal

I want to make an App using Xamarin.Android (which includes OpenTK library that contains an OpenAL Wrapper) that processes audio files (changes pitch, speeds up, slows down or reverse the audio). I know nothing about audio files or OpenAL and there seems to be no tutorials for OpenTK's OpenAL wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I suggest checking out the [included example](https://github.com/mono/opentk/blob/e5859900d3a41885e03be46b492bfd382442f130/Source/Examples/OpenAL/1.1/Playback.cs), that will at least get you playing something.

Also, there are many vanilla OpenAL tutorials floating around the internet, I'd check those out next. The OpenTK function names, parameters, etc are essentially identical.

Alternatively, check out [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio), another c# audio library. You'll find many YouTube tutorials for this one.

Comment: Thanks, the OpenAL example is useful. However I still need to search for a library that converts MP3 and other audio formats to WAV and vice versa so that I can use it. NAudio seems to be using Windows only libraries but I'm developing an android app. But thanks anyways!

Comment: NAudio can convert between, but yeh Windows only. Good luck comrade.